Vugen: web_custom_request in a for loop how to send the calls parallely
I have a for web_custom_request inside a for loop. How to send the calls inside the loop parallel.
Code:
Web_concurrent_start(NULL);
For(i=0;i<=5;i++){
Web_custom_request ();
}
Web_concurrent_end(NULL);
